# Get value from a textarea and place it in a new textarea with some added texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. I have a textarea (txtar1) that will be filled up by a user with HTML codes.
2. I have a 'generate' button;
3. When the 'generate button is clicked, the value from txtar1 will be placed in a another textarea (txtar2). But with some added css code.

here's what I've done:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><label>Enter HTML Code : </label></td>
    <td><textarea id="htmlcode_txtarea"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="" id="submit_btn" value="Generate" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="new_html">
    <td><label>New HTML</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="new_htmlcode_txtarea"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

javascript/jquery:

```
jQuery('#submit_btn').click(function(){ 
    var newVal = jQuery('#htmlcode_txtarea').attr('value');
    var addVal = "#af-form-1031686823 .af-element{float:left;}" + 
                "#af-form-1031686823 .af-clear{display:none}:" + 
                "#af-form-1031686823 .af-body input.text{width: 150px!important;margin0right:15px!important}" +
                "#af-form-1031686823 .buttonContainer{margin-top:-6px!important}";


    jQuery('#new_html').show();
    jQuery('#new_htmlcode_txtarea').attr('value',newVal);
});
```

What should i Do?

Comment: use `.val()` instead of `attr('value')` for a start

Comment: @ManseUK I fear it's not the point here...

Comment: Perhaps you should better state your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easy wato achieve is make use of [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function

```
$("#textarea2").val($("#textarea1").val() + "text to append ")
```